# Get keys and values ​from this object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I hope you are well. Well, I have this const that I have to store only the keys in bold. Can someone help me? Thanks.

```
const weather =  {"lat":38.7267,"lon":-9.1403,"timezone":"Europe/Lisbon","timezone_offset":0,"daily":
[{**"dt":1643716800**,"sunrise":1643701358,"sunset":1643738251,"moonrise":1643703300,"moonset":1643739480,"moon_phase":0,"temp":{**"day":14.64**,"min":7.87,"max":17.88,"night":11.23,"eve":17.11,"morn":8.87},"feels_like":
{"day":13.26,"night":10.05,"eve":15.95,"morn":6.74},"pressure":1030,"humidity":42,"dew_point":2.04,"wind_speed":5.93,"wind_deg":63,"wind_gust":10.3,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":0,"pop":0,"uvi":2.77},
{**"dt":1643803200**,"sunrise":1643787705,"sunset":1643824721,"moonrise":1643791980,"moonset":1643830320,"moon_phase":0.05,"temp":
{**"day":14.15**,"min":8.57,"max":15.82,"night":12.23,"eve":13.4,"morn":8.86},"feels_like":
{"day":12.87,"night":11.31,"eve":12.36,"morn":7.19},"pressure":1027,"humidity":48,"dew_point":3.31,"wind_speed":3.09,"wind_deg":59,"wind_gust":4.62,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":1,"pop":0,"uvi":2.81},
{**"dt":1643889600**,"sunrise":1643874051,"sunset":1643911191,"moonrise":1643880300,"moonset":1643920920,"moon_phase":0.08,"temp":{**"day":14.87**,"min":10.71,"max":16.29,"night":11.89,"eve":13.69,"morn":10.97},"feels_like":{"day":14.03,"night":11.22,"eve":12.86,"morn":10.21},"pressure":1026,"humidity":62,"dew_point":7.74,"wind_speed":3.39,"wind_deg":312,"wind_gust":5.61,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":100,"pop":0,"uvi":2.24},{**"dt":1643976000**,"sunrise":1643960394,"sunset":1643997661,"moonrise":1643968320,"moonset":1644011340,"moon_phase":0.12,"temp":
{**"day":14.29**,"min":10.44,"max":14.85,"night":12.06,"eve":12.76,"morn":10.44},"feels_like":
{"day":13.39,"night":11.15,"eve":11.84,"morn":9.81},"pressure":1026,"humidity":62,"dew_point":7.22,"wind_speed":5.42,"wind_deg":341,"wind_gust":7.64,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":100,"pop":0,"uvi":2.2},
{**"dt":1644062400**,"sunrise":1644046737,"sunset":1644084131,"moonrise":1644056220,"moonset":1644101580,"moon_phase":0.15,"temp":
{**"day":14.11**,"min":9.78,"max":15.67,"night":11.21,"eve":13.4,"morn":9.78},"feels_like":
{"day":13.33,"night":10.4,"eve":12.7,"morn":8.88},"pressure":1024,"humidity":67,"dew_point":7.92,"wind_speed":3.7,"wind_deg":329,"wind_gust":6.98,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":29,"pop":0,"uvi":2.78},
{**"dt":1644148800**,"sunrise":1644133077,"sunset":1644170600,"moonrise":1644144120,"moonset":1644191700,"moon_phase":0.18,"temp":
{**"day":14.1**,"min":8.95,"max":16.45,"night":13.19,"eve":14.37,"morn":8.95},"feels_like":
{"day":13.05,"night":12.34,"eve":13.48,"morn":7.73},"pressure":1026,"humidity":57,"dew_point":5.62,"wind_speed":2.78,"wind_deg":51,"wind_gust":3.97,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":44,"pop":0,"uvi":3},
{**"dt":1644235200**,"sunrise":1644219416,"sunset":1644257070,"moonrise":1644232020,"moonset":0,"moon_phase":0.22,"temp":
{**"day":15.24**,"min":10.12,"max":17.53,"night":13.41,"eve":15.6,"morn":10.12},"feels_like":
{"day":14.33,"night":12.71,"eve":14.91,"morn":9.3},"pressure":1027,"humidity":58,"dew_point":7.18,"wind_speed":2.76,"wind_deg":56,"wind_gust":4.14,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":1,"pop":0,"uvi":3},
{**"dt":1644321600**,"sunrise":1644305754,"sunset":1644343539,"moonrise":1644320040,"moonset":1644281760,"moon_phase":0.25,"temp":
{**"day":15.81**,"min":10.29,"max":18.31,"night":13.72,"eve":16.25,"morn":10.29},"feels_like":
{"day":14.93,"night":12.98,"eve":15.52,"morn":9.44},"pressure":1030,"humidity":57,"dew_point":7.45,"wind_speed":3.22,"wind_deg":46,"wind_gust":5.21,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":17,"pop":0,"uvi":3}]}
```

Comment: You'll need to clarify because there's nothing in bold. Note that putting your code as a code block means regular markdown has no effect.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: @Nultiton, please read the comments to understand why your edit was not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use destructuring:

```js
const weather = {"lat":38.7267,"lon":-9.1403,"timezone":"Europe/Lisbon","timezone_offset":0,"daily":[{"dt":1643716800,"sunrise":1643701358,"sunset":1643738251,"moonrise":1643703300,"moonset":1643739480,"moon_phase":0,"temp":{"day":14.64,"min":7.87,"max":17.88,"night":11.23,"eve":17.11,"morn":8.87},"feels_like":{"day":13.26,"night":10.05,"eve":15.95,"morn":6.74},"pressure":1030,"humidity":42,"dew_point":2.04,"wind_speed":5.93,"wind_deg":63,"wind_gust":10.3,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":0,"pop":0,"uvi":2.77},{"dt":1643803200,"sunrise":1643787705,"sunset":1643824721,"moonrise":1643791980,"moonset":1643830320,"moon_phase":0.05,"temp":{"day":14.15,"min":8.57,"max":15.82,"night":12.23,"eve":13.4,"morn":8.86},"feels_like":{"day":12.87,"night":11.31,"eve":12.36,"morn":7.19},"pressure":1027,"humidity":48,"dew_point":3.31,"wind_speed":3.09,"wind_deg":59,"wind_gust":4.62,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":1,"pop":0,"uvi":2.81},{"dt":1643889600,"sunrise":1643874051,"sunset":1643911191,"moonrise":1643880300,"moonset":1643920920,"moon_phase":0.08,"temp":{"day":14.87,"min":10.71,"max":16.29,"night":11.89,"eve":13.69,"morn":10.97},"feels_like":{"day":14.03,"night":11.22,"eve":12.86,"morn":10.21},"pressure":1026,"humidity":62,"dew_point":7.74,"wind_speed":3.39,"wind_deg":312,"wind_gust":5.61,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":100,"pop":0,"uvi":2.24},{"dt":1643976000,"sunrise":1643960394,"sunset":1643997661,"moonrise":1643968320,"moonset":1644011340,"moon_phase":0.12,"temp":{"day":14.29,"min":10.44,"max":14.85,"night":12.06,"eve":12.76,"morn":10.44},"feels_like":{"day":13.39,"night":11.15,"eve":11.84,"morn":9.81},"pressure":1026,"humidity":62,"dew_point":7.22,"wind_speed":5.42,"wind_deg":341,"wind_gust":7.64,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":100,"pop":0,"uvi":2.2},{"dt":1644062400,"sunrise":1644046737,"sunset":1644084131,"moonrise":1644056220,"moonset":1644101580,"moon_phase":0.15,"temp":{"day":14.11,"min":9.78,"max":15.67,"night":11.21,"eve":13.4,"morn":9.78},"feels_like":{"day":13.33,"night":10.4,"eve":12.7,"morn":8.88},"pressure":1024,"humidity":67,"dew_point":7.92,"wind_speed":3.7,"wind_deg":329,"wind_gust":6.98,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":29,"pop":0,"uvi":2.78},{"dt":1644148800,"sunrise":1644133077,"sunset":1644170600,"moonrise":1644144120,"moonset":1644191700,"moon_phase":0.18,"temp":{"day":14.1,"min":8.95,"max":16.45,"night":13.19,"eve":14.37,"morn":8.95},"feels_like":{"day":13.05,"night":12.34,"eve":13.48,"morn":7.73},"pressure":1026,"humidity":57,"dew_point":5.62,"wind_speed":2.78,"wind_deg":51,"wind_gust":3.97,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":44,"pop":0,"uvi":3},{"dt":1644235200,"sunrise":1644219416,"sunset":1644257070,"moonrise":1644232020,"moonset":0,"moon_phase":0.22,"temp":{"day":15.24,"min":10.12,"max":17.53,"night":13.41,"eve":15.6,"morn":10.12},"feels_like":{"day":14.33,"night":12.71,"eve":14.91,"morn":9.3},"pressure":1027,"humidity":58,"dew_point":7.18,"wind_speed":2.76,"wind_deg":56,"wind_gust":4.14,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":1,"pop":0,"uvi":3},{"dt":1644321600,"sunrise":1644305754,"sunset":1644343539,"moonrise":1644320040,"moonset":1644281760,"moon_phase":0.25,"temp":{"day":15.81,"min":10.29,"max":18.31,"night":13.72,"eve":16.25,"morn":10.29},"feels_like":{"day":14.93,"night":12.98,"eve":15.52,"morn":9.44},"pressure":1030,"humidity":57,"dew_point":7.45,"wind_speed":3.22,"wind_deg":46,"wind_gust":5.21,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":17,"pop":0,"uvi":3}]};

let result = weather.daily.map(({dt, temp: {day}}) => ({dt, day}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the objects in the `daily` array with this Javascript:

```js
weather.daily = weather.daily.map(e => {return {'dt':e.dt, 'temp':{'day':e.temp.day}}})
```